# Given two columns, Insert a value at a specific position in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, replacement

Situation:

[image: Screenshot of cells]

I have two columns A and B. I want the third column C based on the position (specified by B) of the values (specified by A). For empty cells in C, I want to have 0.

How can I do this in Excel?

I tried with `INDEX` and `VLOOKUP` functions, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want. Please confirm.

Sample data is in Cells A1:C8. Row 1 is the header.

The formula in C2 is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH((ROW()-ROW($D$1)),$B$2:$B$6,0)),0)
```

Drag it down along the length of the intended rows.
Since the data starts in Row 2, ROW () - ROW ($D$1) starts the Index with 1 and further for the MATCH Function. It can be changed to ROW() - ROW($C$1) too. Just need a constant 1.
To simplify it you may use below as long as your data always starts in row 2.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH((ROW()-1),$B$2:$B$6,0)),0)
```

Depending upon your regional settings you might need to replace comma in the formula with semicolon.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of ```$D$1``` in your command?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: This works for the given problem. In my original problem (not stated here), the values of ```Fruits``` and ```Position``` are generated using formulas. Substituting the above range by the formulas didn't give me the desired result. Is there is a way to insert values (generated by a formula) at a specific position (also generated by a formula)?

Comment: I have asked another question stating my main problem. Thank you for your help on this one.