# Given multiple columns, insert a value at a particular position in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Previously, I thought reducing my original problem to a simpler one would help, and thus I asked this question: [Given two columns, Insert a value at a specific position in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1689601/given-two-columns-insert-a-value-at-a-specific-position-in-excel)

Turns out, my original problem is still unsolved.

So here is the situation of my original problem:

[image]

All the repetitions in the `House` column means the members belong to the same house. Each member has a `Preference`, and its order is given in `PreferencesOrder` column. The fourth column `HouseID` can be ignored; I included it thinking that it could be useful to answering my question.

Each of these columns has 10000 values.

There are altogether 8 types of preferences, so the order of a preference can take any values between 1 and 8.

Now, what I want is the following result.

[image]

I used the following command

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10000, SMALL(IF($D2=$A$2:$A$10000, ROW($A$2:$A$10000)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$10000))+1, ""), E$1)),0)`

This does not consider the ranking of the preferences, so gives me the following output

[image]

This is not exactly what I want; it misses the ranking of the preferences. How can I change my code to consider the ranking of the preferences? Or how I can do this more efficiently?

Comment: You write "*HouseID can be ignored;*", yet it is in your desired output picture. And the actual *House* is **not** included in your output.  Please clarify.

Comment: `House` is not included in the output because all the preferences for a house go in a row. `HouseID` is included in the output just to refer that each row in the output correspond to each house. Please let me know if this did not clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365, and if your desired output is incorrect given your input, and the column you labelled `House ID` in your output is really the `House`, then you can use the following formula:

```
H2: =IFERROR(FILTER(Pref[[Preferences]:[Preferences]],(Pref[[House]:[House]]=$G2)*(Pref[[Preferences Rank]:[Preferences Rank]]=COLUMNS($A:A))),0)
```

*then fill down and across to fill the table*

If you have an earlier version, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Pref[[Preferences]:[Preferences]],AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((Pref[[House]:[House]]=$G2)*(Pref[[Preferences Rank]:[Preferences Rank]]=COLUMNS($A:A)))*ROW(Pref),1)-ROW(Pref[#Headers])),0)
```

Note that I named your "original problem" table `Pref` and I am using structured references, but you can change this to regular addressing if you prefer.

**Input**
[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, how can this be done without referencing the entire table? I did not understand the part that used `Pref`.

Comment: @specfunctor   what portion of the table do you want to exclude? Suggest you research Excel tables and structured references  for better understanding. A tutorial on that topic is too long to include in an answer in this forum.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that topic. But I am curious to know if there is a way to modify my code to include the ranking of the preferences. That is, can this be done without using references to the table?

Comment: @specfunctorb Possibly. I  suggest you post the particulars as a new question  with examples of  exactly what you want to do.  In the meantime, if this answer satisfies your current question, kindly mark it as accepted

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. Delighted to have learnt this.